# Tkinter: StringVar is empty

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I creating a little application by Python using Tkinter and sqlite3. Now i trying to make an authentification by login and signup. But when i trying to get value from entry StringVar (to get user login and password), its always '' empty, and i dont know how to fix it. Here`s my code:

```
class startWindow:

    def __init__(self):

        window = Tk()
        window.geometry("150x100")
        window.title('SignUp and LogIn')

        def sign_window():

            sign_window = Tk()
            sign_window.geometry('200x150')
            sign_window.title('SignUp')

            enterNumberLabel = Label(sign_window, text='Enter your Phone')
            enterNumberLabel.grid(row=1)

            number_text = StringVar()
            enterNumberEntry = Entry(sign_window, textvariable=number_text)
            enterNumberEntry.grid(row=2)

            enterPasswordLabel = Label(sign_window, text='Password')
            enterPasswordLabel.grid(row=3)

            password_text = StringVar()
            enterPasswordEntry = Entry(sign_window, textvariable=password_text)
            enterPasswordEntry.grid(row=4)

            def add_user_to_db():
                print(password_text.get())
                DB().add_new_user(number_text.get(), password_text.get())
```

I tested and realized StringVar is working when its one def in code, but my task requesting it several.

Comment: Don't use the same name `sign_window` for the function and a variable, it's confusing.

Comment: How are you calling `add_user_to_db()`? Make sure it's called after the user has filled in the entries.

Comment: Don't create two different `Tk()` toplevels. Use `StartWindow.window` instead of creating `sign_window`.

Comment: You are creating multiple instances of `Tk()`, each of which has its own entirely separate set of Vars.  Use `Toplevel()` instead, to create additional windows that live in the same `Tk` instance.

Comment: Thanks! Toplevel() helped me with problem!